# Regeneration specifics: activation of the ability in combat

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-regenerate

I'm aware of [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4546/how-does-regeneration-work-in-magic-the-gathering) about regeneration, which covers *almost* everything about it, but the focus of that question was on instants such as [Shock](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShock%5d) or [Doom Blade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoom%20Blade%5d). My question is different and wasn't answered by that post.

If I block a 5/5 creature with two 4/4 creatures that both have a regeneration ability, but I only have enough mana to regenerate *one* of my creatures, can I regenerate after my opponent has assigned lethal damage to one of my creatures?

Does the creature immediately die from lethal damage since I can't predict where said damage will go (and therefore can't activate the shield beforehand), or can I still regenerate it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does regeneration work in Magic the Gathering?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4546/how-does-regeneration-work-in-magic-the-gathering)

Comment: See the accepted answer in that duplicate question where it states *The only condition is that the regeneration has to happen before the destruction effect.* Combat damage no longer uses the stack.

Comment: See also: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6047/when-must-an-instant-be-played-that-prevents-damage

Comment: @ghoppe see also the first sentence in my post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the declare blockers step, the attacker must specify the order of the blocking creatures.

What that means, in the scope of your question, is that the owner of the 5/5 creature must declare which of your 4/4s he is going to deal damage to first.  As such, you have a pretty good idea which creature you want to regenerate: the one the attacker put first into the firing line!  Unless something else happens, that creature will take 4 damage and be regenerated, the other creature will take 1 damage, and both your blockers will survive.